# python boto3 ecr start_image_scan erroring out with "[ERROR] TypeError: start_image_scan() only accepts keyword arguments."

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm trying to create an AWS lambda script to automate scanning ecr (Elastic Container Registry) images. I have a lambda (python) that loops through my images and gives a boto3 start_image_scan command to initiate a scan. The code works to generate the input to the start_image_scan(). If I use the input to initiate the scan it fails with the error "[ERROR] TypeError: start_image_scan() only accepts keyword arguments." If I hard code the output into the command it works. I've tried a couple of ways to cast the input to a string. I've included them in the code as comments. They failed with the same error message. Any input anyone has would be greatly appreciated.

```
import json
import boto3


def get_reponames():
    client = boto3.client('ecr')
    reponames = [repo['repositoryName'] for repo in client.describe_repositories()['repositories']]

    return reponames


def get_imageids(prepo):
    client = boto3.client('ecr')
    imageids = [
        {"imageDigest": img['imageDigest'], "imageTag": img.get('imageTag', None)} for img in
        client.list_images(repositoryName=prepo, )['imageIds']
    ]

    return imageids


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('ecr')
    output = get_reponames()
    for rn in output:
        outputii = get_imageids(rn)
        for ii in outputii:
            if ii['imageTag'].lower() == "latest":
                print("scan this image")
                scanid = 'repositoryName="'+rn+'", imageId={"imageDigest": "'+ii['imageDigest']+'", "imageTag": "'+ii['imageTag']+'"}'
                # scanid = (json.dumps('repositoryName="'+rn+'", imageId={"imageDigest": "'+ii['imageDigest']+'", "imageTag": "'+ii['imageTag']+'"}').replace("\\", ""))[1:-1]
                # scanid = (str('repositoryName="'+rn+'", imageId={"imageDigest": "'+ii['imageDigest']+'", "imageTag": "'+ii['imageTag']+'"}')
                print(scanid)
                # client.start_image_scan(repositoryName="testimage", imageId={'imageDigest': 'sha256:24d7013a7b2805accd177279c6549d08e45059cc5696e32f5c0184f3652daaaa', 'imageTag': '15'})
                client.start_image_scan(scanid)
            else:
                print("DONT SCAN")

    return {
        'body': json.dumps("hello world")
    }
```

Comment: HI maybe try:
client.start_image_scan(repositoryName=%s, imageId={'imageDigest': %s, 'imageTag': %s} % (value1, value2, value 3))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow the signature of the method, per the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecr.html#ECR.Client.start_image_scan).

```py
client.start_image_scan(repositoryName=rn, imageId={'imageDigest': ii['imageDigest']})
```

You also only need to specify one identifier -- the tag or the digest, not necessarily both.

Since you seem to only want to scan the `latest` tag, you could also just do the following:

```py
client.start_image_scan(repositoryName=rn, imageId={'imageTag': 'latest'})
```